# Swift - Error : Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

Tags: post, server, vapor

I want to connect a web server to my ios application with swift. So I created a function to create a task with "POST" but when I call it, I get an error message :

> nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

My code :

```
func createDish(dish :Dish) {
   
    let url = URL(string :"http://localhost:8080/dish)!
    var request = URLRequest(url :url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(dish) {
        request.httpBody = data
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let data = data {
            if let dish = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Dish.self, from: data)
            {
                self.dishes.append(dish)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I don't know at all where the error comes from, if it's in my app or server code. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to local host indeed? Can you access this url in browser from the same device? Did you try `https` instead?

Comment: This would be an issue with connecting to your MySQL database. Make sure that MySQL is running and that your connection configuration for your Vapor server matches what you have for your MySQL database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

After replacing the localhost with a machine's IP address(ex, 192.168.100.XXX), it worked well.

How to find my ip on a mac:

https://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/?fbclid=IwAR1oiq4xyvAWj9XOaG3VzGdr6TIyIbFE08PzCZLNbEu2RaQf4LUWCkFGQgY

Comment: For finding my local IP address, I just add this alias to my `.zshrc` file `alias myip='ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d" " -f2'`. I restart my shell, then type `myip`.

Comment: Or you could try 127.0.0.1 which worked for me.